# No option to enable Hyper-V in my BIOS settings

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, virtualization, hyper-v, bios

I am new to Windows Phone 8 application development. I installed SDK 8.0. When I run my application, it shows an error telling me to enable Hyper-V. While searching, I found [this MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj863509%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
 with a solution in the BIOS. But when go to my BIOS settings, then there are no such options available .

Any suggestions?

Comment: I added step 2, which is important! Sorry I forgot to mention it at first.

Comment: sir in that features tab , no hyper-v checkbox. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4BFBh3OR4u0TDJxVlpybUgzZ3M/edit?usp=sharing
 see the snapshot.

Comment: Edited my answer, but I should ask: are you running Windows 8 Pro or Windows 8 Enterprise? Hyper-V does not ship with basic Windows 8.

Comment: thanks a lot . i have to install window 8.1. 
i'll be thank full to you

Comment: Please mark as the answer when/if you verify that this enables Hyper-V. I've done this 2-3 times at work, so my instructions should help.

Comment: will the window 8.1 preview set up will solve my problem ?

Comment: Only if you install Windows 8.1 Pro or Windows 8.1 Enterprise. Basic/vanilla Windows 8.1 does not come with the Hyper-V feature.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Step 1: Enable Virtualization in BIOS**

You need to enable `Virtualization Technology (VTx)` under the `System Security` option in the `Security` tab of your BIOS management menu.

The option may not be called `Virtualization Technology` or have the term `VTx` or `VT-x` in it. It may be called `Hardware Virtualization` or `Virtualization`, etc. Also, the option may not be under the Security tab. Since virtualization is hardware-dependent and BIOS interfaces can differ wildly, you may have to do some digging.

**Step 2: Enable Hyper-V**

You will also need to turn the Hyper-V feature on (it's not enabled in Windows 8 by default).

*From Programs and Features Menu:*

1. Go to: Control Panel >> Programs and Features >> click “Turn Windows features on or off” (should be on the left panel).
2. Check the “Hyper-V” checkbox in that list, then click OK.
3. Wait for the installation to finish, then reboot.

**OR**

*In Powershell*

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature –FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All
```

You should then be able to use Hyper-V.

See this [step by step](http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2013/11/05/step-by-step-enabling-hyper-v-for-use-on-windows-8-1.aspx) guide for screenshots.

**Notes**

1. You must be running Windows 8 Pro or Windows 8 Enterprise. Hyper-V is not available in basic Windows 8. Same applies to Windows 8.1.
2. Your CPU may not support VTx. Use [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) to find out. Run CPU-Z, then click the 'CPU' tab at the top. There should be a label called `Instructions` on the left, about halfway down the window. If you do not see `VT-x` listed there, your CPU doesn't support it, and you're out of luck, I'm afraid.

Comment: but there is only virtualization not virtualization technology (vtx)

Comment: @AmitKumar Does you CPU support VTx? See above.

Comment: yes , there is vt-x tab. but still can not find virtualzation technology in bios settings. i have snapshot of bios settings. but unable to post the images here

Comment: sir unable to post image here . can i have your email id please . i need help sir .

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4BFBh3OR4u0Y1N6VkNtZjRyRnc/edit?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4BFBh3OR4u0NFRUS1lmUW9jUXM/edit?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4BFBh3OR4u0WllSTjBfWjlxaWM/edit?usp=sharing
sir these are the snapshot . please check it

Comment: Read my answer carefully: it's under the `Security` tab, which is to the right of the `Advanced` tab from your screenshot.

Comment: sir i have sent you the security tab too . but there is no option of System Security in bios setting => security tab. 
please check all 3 images .

Answer (score 1):

For those who haven't found a solution for this, I cracked my head around it for a couple of days since my BIOS doesn't have the option to enable it. I found out that you must run the intel hardware execution manager as an administrator and if you have Avast antivirus go to settings/troubleshooting/ and disable (uncheck) hardware assited virtualization. Apparently the option is already enabled in BIOS. Hope this works for you.