# Problems with android emulator in xamarin project MS VS 2015

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, android-emulator

I have installed MS VS 2015. I've installed xamarin with all required staff like Android sdk etc. I have this options for xamarin project:
[image]
For both options I get this errors:

```
2>emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
2>Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
2>CPU acceleration status: Android Emulator requires an Intel processor with VT-x and NX support.  Your CPU: 'AuthenticAMD'
```

How to fix it?

Comment: [This guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/accelerating_android_emulators/) explains how to install and configure the Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM) to make the Google Android Emulator run faster on supported systems.

Answer (score 1):

You find the details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26883295/2653134) on stackoverflow:

> In current AVD manager you can't. You just have the opportunity to use
>   ARM images which will not need hardware virtualization.

but, have you tried the [Visual Studio Android Emulator](https://www.visualstudio.com/de/vs/msft-android-emulator/)? This emulator is a lot faster then the images from Google and it's free. We use this Emulator and it works like a charm.

Check the [system requirements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228280.aspx) to ensure, the emulator works on your machine.

**Edit**

To enable Hyper-V look at [this detailted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21074680/2653134). But note:

> You must be running Windows 8 Pro or Windows 8 Enterprise. Hyper-V is
>   not available in basic Windows 8. Same applies to Windows 8.1.
>
> Your CPU may not support Virtualization Technology (VTx)

Comment: Unfortunately there are no settings like "Hyper-V" etc. in my BIOS.